# Nested \underset screws up size – is there a better way?

Tags: symbols

I often find myself wanting two or more conditions below a sum, supremum, limit, etc.  Currently, the only way I know to typeset this is using an `\underset` inside another `\underset`.  For example,

```
\|A\|= \underset{\underset{\|\eta\|=1}{\|\xi\|=1}}{\sup} |\langle A\xi, \eta \rangle|
```

or

```
\underset{\underset{i_1+\dots+i_k=n}{i_1<\dots<i_k}}{\sum} x_1^{i_1} \dots x_k^{i_k}.
```

What I don't like about this is that the two lines under the sum, sup, lim, or whatever end up a different size, and I'd really like them to be equal.  Is there a more flexible way to create multiline expressions under these symbols?  (I tried putting a `\\` inside the first argument of `\underset`, but it didn't work.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `\substack` or the `subarray` environment of the `amsmath` package.

For example:

```
\|A\|= \sup\limits_{\substack{\|\eta\|=1\\\|\xi\|=1}} |\langle A\xi, \eta \rangle|
```

You can omit `\limits` in `displaymath` mode. Of course `\substack` and `subarray` can also be combined with `\underset`.

Here's an example for `\underset` with `subarray`:

```
\underset{\begin{subarray}{c}
  i_1+\dots+i_k=n \\
  i_1<\dots<i_k
  \end{subarray}}{\sum} x_1^{i_1} \dots x_k^{i_k}.
```

With `subarray` you can achieve left alignment by specifying `l` instead of `c`. `r` However, `r` doesn't work for right aligment, if one expects that.